# Neo4j movies dataset

Tags: neo4j

am new to neo4j and I want to know how to query for example, in movies dataset,"Which movie has the most number of actors in it?" and Which pair of actors have acted together in most number of movies?

Comment: What did you try? Which of the plenty available online resources did you use?

Answer (score 1):

Below questions are not new.  You just need to know how to find them.

1. Which movie has the most number of actors in it?

[Find the movie with the largest cast, out of the list of movies that have a review](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53217216/find-the-movie-with-the-largest-cast-out-of-the-list-of-movies-that-have-a-revi)

2. Which pair of actors have acted together in most number of movies?

[Pair of Actors with Most Occurences](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58967136/pair-of-actors-with-most-occurences)